# JqueryMobile Really fixed footer on iPhone 3Gs

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

i would like to have a really fixed toolbal on iPhone 3G with JQM 1.1, 

not working if content is too short.

[image: Not fixed footer if short conent]

Can anybody help, how to solve it?

Many tahnks